# File handling in pic32

Tags: c, csv, embedded

I am using CSV file format for back end purpose, I supposed to update CSV file frequently, so i used to open `status.csv` file in `r+` mode.The problem is I couldn't close that CSV, if i do, it goes to exception handling.if i leave it opened, it occupies the heap memory that leads to many problems.

```
    FSFILE *tp;
    enrowbuf=atoi(httemp);  
    FSchdir("\\"); 
    FSchdir("WWW");
    FSchdir("DBMS"); 
    tp = FSfopen("Status.csv","r+");
    if(tp!=NULL)
        {
        if(enrowbuf==1)
            {
            FSfseek(tp,(43*enrowbuf),SEEK_SET);
            }
        else
            {
            FSfseek(tp,(42*enrowbuf),SEEK_SET);
            FSfwrite(&Relay4,48,1,tp);
            }
        FSfclose(tp);
        }
```

Comment: The docs for FSfwrite have a Precondition section which says 'File is opened in write (w) or append (a) mode'.  So, although `r+` is normally associated with reading/writing, perhaps this library forces you to open in `a` or `w` mode?

Comment: @AustinPhillips: Can you give a URL to support your contention that a file must be opened for write or append mode, and that read/update mode is not allowed. There are likely to be problems with the output if you go interpolating records of variable length in the middle of a file, but if `FSfwrite()` is an accurate analogue of `fwrite()`, then it should write in the middle of a file.  Since I'm not clear what the significance of the FS prefix is, I may be barking up the wrong tree, but then I'd expect to find that `a` or `a+` mode made sense (and plain `w` or `w+` did not).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My reference was http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01045a.pdf, p22 - I'm assuming this is the library referred to in the question but I may be wrong.  Unfortunately, my experience is that these type of embedded system libraries are notorious for being non-standard and cut corners in the implementation due to resource constraints.

Comment: @AustinPhillips: thanks for the PDF manual URL.  The `FSfopen()` function takes just 3 variations for the mode argument: `"r"`, `"w"`, and `"a"`.  There are no update modes, etc. Thus, the use of `"r+"` is out of spec, but most likely opens the file in read (only) mode, no writing allowed.  Maybe error checking the `FSfwrite()` call would help. I'm glad I was cautious about arguing by analogy as the analogy (with `fwrite()`) is clearly flawed. Your answer was close to accurate.  Since the file opens (`tp != NULL`), the library doesn't check the second character of the mode string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried this and its working fine, i opened the file in append mode `a`. Heap memory gets cleared by closing the file properly.

```
    FSFILE *tp;
    enrowbuf=atoi(httemp);  
    FSchdir("\\"); 
    FSchdir("WWW");
    FSchdir("DBMS"); 
    tp = FSfopen("Status.csv","a");
    if(tp!=NULL)
        {
        if(enrowbuf==1)
            {
            FSfseek(tp,(43*enrowbuf),SEEK_SET);
            }
        else
            {
            FSfseek(tp,(42*enrowbuf),SEEK_SET);
            FSfwrite(&Relay4,48,1,tp);
            }
        FSfclose(tp);
        }
```